# Android Canvas - How to avoid drawing something static?

Tags: android, canvas

I have a custom View where i draw something on it on `onDraw`.

On every `onDraw` i draw the background ( some basic triangle and circle ) and then i draw something that looks different every time i draw it.

How can i draw the background ( the static stuff ) once and just leave it as it is? Because drawing the background seems to put a lot of strain on the GPU since the other animations seem to slow down ( drawer pulling out and ripple animations )

How can i avoid not drawing it on every `onDraw`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a bitmap.  Create a Bitmap object, then create a Canvas passing that Bitmap in as a parameter.  Draw whatever you want to that canvas.  That Bitmap now holds your static drawing.  In your onDraw function, first draw the static bitmap to the canvas passed into onDraw.  Then draw your dynamic data.  This is actually a good way of doing things, since drawing a bitmap is relatively fast.

Comment: Thanks :) Just one more question... On my custom view's onDraw method... the first few calls return incorrect height... I'm guessing that's just because the layout hasn't been finished ordering views and stuff like that? How do i solve that?

Comment: @FilipPetrovic - Did you find a solution? I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan - I'm using your approach, however, I'm having the following concern: On a full-screen game, the background will have the size of the whole screen. Creating a bitmap that will be the size of the whole screen might cause an OutOfMemoryError. Do you have any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two views- one view holds the background and other view on top of background-view.

You don't invalidate the view which holds the background each time you do animation.

You can use FrameLayout to have a view on top of each other.

Comment: I'm doing that exact thing, however, I notice that if I draw lots of stuff via canvas on the background view, the UI begins to stutter. I draw the view only once, I do not invalidate it each time. The problem is that this stuttering is constant, even when the view is drawn only once. Is there any workaround on that?